# I don't understand a paragraph about tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, self-learning

[image]

I don't understand how author associate the smooth manifolds and linear subspace.
TM is a linear subspace,what 's the mean of T?A set of vector?

And find the definition on Wikipedia.

[image]

I still don't understand what's tangent space,because I dont know what's the mean of Ck.

then I looked up it on wolfram mathworld.

[image]

I don't know what 's the mean of "attach at  x a copy of R^n tangential to  M."
How to define a space tangential to a manifold?

Comment: What book are you taking the original paragraph from? Almost any book that talks about these objects should define them for the context in which they would like to speak about them. Wikipedia also has all the relevant definitions for differentiable manifold, tangent space, etc.

Comment: Milnor, differential topology.I'm consulting gtm 191 now.@BrianKlatt

Comment: 1. $C^k$-function means a function so that all partial derivatives of order $\le k$ exist and are continuous. A $C^k$-manifold is a differentiable manifold where transition maps are $C^k$. Is it what you wanted to know? 2. The definition is MathWorld is sloppy and best to be avoided.

Comment: As I recall, Milnor works by defining manifolds as smooth subsets of some high dimensional Euclidean space, so the tangent space at a point $p$ in $M$ can be defined as the set of all possible tangent vectors $\dot{\gamma} (0)$ to curves in $M$ such that $\gamma (0)=p$.

Comment: One way to define the derivative of a smooth function $f$ is then $df_x(\dot{\gamma}(0))=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ \gamma)(0)$.

Comment: @studiosus 1.thanks,but the definition of Ck is more complex in gtm 191,and I feel you give a totally different definition.I'm more confused now.2.thank you for your advice.

Comment: @BrianKlatt Thanks .I know  tangent space  is the set of tangent vector.but what kind of tangent vector?How to define a tangent vector without geometry.

Comment: @program666: If you want to consider only manifolds embedded in some $R^n$, then the definition of an $m$-dimensional $C^k$-smooth manifold $M\subset R^n$ is as follows: For every point $p\in M$ there exists a local $C^k$-chart $F: R^m\to M$ sending $0$ to $p$; a chart in this context means a $C^k$-map whose derivative is injective at every point of the domain. There are other equivalent definitions, but this one is most relevant for you. With this definition, you can think of $T_pM$ as the image of the derivative $DF(0): R^m\to R^n$.

Comment: @studiosus ok,I get it.by the way ,does Ck have a name?

Comment: Calvin Klein sounds good to me:). Other people simply call it $C^k$.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "define tangent vector without geometry."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a manifold embedded in some $\mathbb R^n$, and a set of coordinates on that manifold $x^1, x^2, \ldots, x^m$, then each point on the manifold is a position vector, a function of the coordinates like so:  $r = r(x^1, x^2, \ldots, x^m)$.

Each partial derivative of that function, $\partial r/\partial x^1, \partial r/\partial x^2, \ldots$ is a vector field on the manifold.  At a given point $p$, they give us so-called a basis of tangent vectors--vectors tangent to the manifold.

The span of these tangent vectors at $p$ gives us the *tangent space* at $p$.  Because each of these tangent spaces is a flat vector space, they are essentially the same as copies of $\mathbb R^m$.